# Hibernate comparing collections

Tags: hibernate, select, collections, hql

Is there any possibility in HQL (or native SQL) to compare if collection of entity is the same as collection given in param?

I want to write something like this: `SELECT r FROM Room r  WHERE r.users = :users` while users is list/set of Strings

Comment: only solution I came with, is to create a String field, where users will be ordered & concatenated at save time, and then, when creating query I will order and concatenate param list

Comment: To clarify, with your predicate `r.users = :users` what you mean is that every member of `r.users` must also be present in `:users`. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, the collections must be the same. Every user of `r.users` must be in `:users` and every user of `:users` must be in `r.users`